# Unique values for combination of columns in Hybris Impex Files

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I'm creating a Hybris impex file to import into my Database.

I want to perform an INSERT_UPDATE action with the data from the file, so I need to tell Hybris which column(s) need to be unique, so that it knows when to update a record instead of insert it.

I know that to tell Hybris that a certain column needs to be unique I can add the unique attribute to that column, like this:

```
INSERT_UPDATE SLEmployee;Firstname[unique=true, required=true];Lastname[required=true];Function;
```

But on my example above, how do I tell Hybris that the combination of the columns Firstname + Lastname must be unique?

Comment: Have a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71546100/sap-hybris-how-to-display-specific-products-at-top-results-after-search

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
> how do I tell Hybris that the combination of the 
> columns Firstname + Lastname must be unique?
```

Add the `unique` keyword to every field that is part of the combined key

```
 INSERT_UPDATE SLEmployee;Firstname[unique=true];Lastname[unique=true];Function;
```

Comment: exactly this. you can just add multiple unique attributes to a field and hybris will make sure it matches them all.

Answer (score 0):

While creating attributes in itemtype, make sure unique modifier is set true for all the attributes you want to be considered for the combination. Prepare data accordingly.